# ERROR 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 line in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view in SQL that when I want to open it gives me the following message: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 line.
How can I correct this query considering my sql script?
My code is:

```
SELECT
    `sc`.`id` AS `id`,
    `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado` AS `id_agente_solicitado`,
    `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante` AS `id_agente_solicitante`,
    `sc`.`fecha_solicitada` AS `fecha`,
    `sc`.`horario_solicitado` AS `hora`,
    `sc`.`pendiente` AS `pendiente`,
    '1' AS `tipo`,
    'Cambios de horarios' AS `grupo`,
    '1' AS `grupo_numero`,
    CONCAT(`a`.`nombres`, ' ', `a`.`apellidos`) AS `agente_solicitado_nombre`,
    (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`nombres`,
            ' ',
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`apellidos`
        )
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `agente_solicitante_nombre`,
(
    SELECT
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`imagen_perfil`
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `imagen_perfil_solicitante`,
`a`.`imagen_perfil` AS `imagen_perfil_solicitado`,
DAYNAME(`sc`.`fecha_solicitada`) AS `nombre_dia`,
CONCAT(
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_solicitada`, '%d') USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        MONTHNAME(`sc`.`fecha_solicitada`) USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_solicitada`, '%Y') USING utf8mb4
    )
) AS `nombre_mes`,
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT(' ', `det`.`ingreso`)
    FROM
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`planilla_horarios_det` `det`
        LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`planilla_horarios_cab` `cab`
        ON
            (
                (
                    `cab`.`id_planilla_horarios_cab` = `det`.`id_planilla_horarios_cab`
                )
            )
        )
    WHERE
        (
            (
                STR_TO_DATE(
                    CONCAT(
                        `cab`.`ano_correspondiente`,
                        ',',
                        `cab`.`mes_correspondiente`,
                        ',',
                        `det`.`dia`
                    ),
                    '%Y,%m,%d'
                ) = `sc`.`fecha_solicitada`
            ) AND(
                `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante` = `det`.`id_agente`
            )
        )
) AS `cambio_por`
FROM
    (
        `sigsiste_bd`.`solicitudes_cambio_horario` `sc`
    LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes` `a`
    ON
        (
            (
                `a`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado`
            )
        )
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    `sc`.`id` AS `id`,
    `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado` AS `id_agente_solicitado`,
    `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante` AS `id_agente_solicitante`,
    `sc`.`fecha_cobertura` AS `fecha`,
    `sc`.`horario_cobertura` AS `hora`,
    `sc`.`pendiente` AS `pendiente`,
    '2' AS `tipo`,
    'Coberturas' AS `grupo`,
    '2' AS `grupo_numero`,
    CONCAT(`a`.`nombres`, ' ', `a`.`apellidos`) AS `agente_solicitado_nombre`,
    (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`nombres`,
            ' ',
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`apellidos`
        )
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `agente_solicitante_nombre`,
(
    SELECT
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`imagen_perfil`
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `imagen_perfil_solicitante`,
`a`.`imagen_perfil` AS `imagen_perfil_solicitado`,
DAYNAME(`sc`.`fecha_cobertura`) AS `nombre_dia`,
CONCAT(
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_cobertura`, '%d') USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        MONTHNAME(`sc`.`fecha_cobertura`) USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_cobertura`, '%Y') USING utf8mb4
    )
) AS `nombre_mes`,
'' AS `cambio_por`
FROM
    (
        `sigsiste_bd`.`solicitudes_cobertura` `sc`
    LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes` `a`
    ON
        (
            (
                `a`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado`
            )
        )
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    `sc`.`id` AS `id`,
    `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado` AS `id_agente_solicitado`,
    `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante` AS `id_agente_solicitante`,
    `sc`.`fecha_devolucion` AS `fecha`,
    `sc`.`horario_devolucion` AS `hora`,
    `sc`.`pendiente` AS `pendiente`,
    '3' AS `tipo`,
    'Devoluciones' AS `grupo`,
    '3' AS `grupo_numero`,
    CONCAT(`a`.`nombres`, ' ', `a`.`apellidos`) AS `agente_solicitado_nombre`,
    (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`nombres`,
            ' ',
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`apellidos`
        )
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `agente_solicitante_nombre`,
(
    SELECT
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`imagen_perfil`
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `imagen_perfil_solicitante`,
`a`.`imagen_perfil` AS `imagen_perfil_solicitado`,
DAYNAME(`sc`.`fecha_devolucion`) AS `nombre_dia`,
CONCAT(
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_devolucion`, '%d') USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        MONTHNAME(`sc`.`fecha_devolucion`) USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_devolucion`, '%Y') USING utf8mb4
    )
) AS `nombre_mes`,
'' AS `cambio_por`
FROM
    (
        `sigsiste_bd`.`solicitudes_devoluciones` `sc`
    LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes` `a`
    ON
        (
            (
                `a`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado`
            )
        )
    )
```

I have a view in SQL that after trying to open it gives me the following message: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 line.
How can I correct my query?

Comment: Execute the subqueries one by one and check their result.

Comment: This is a very specific problem which honestly requires the data but as Jonas says run each one to see which one is returning more than 1 row

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to be sure, as you have not included nearly enough detail, but I suspect the error is being caused by the subquery for `cambio_por` as the other subqueries appear to be based on the PK -

```
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT(' ', `det`.`ingreso`)
    FROM
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`planilla_horarios_det` `det`
        LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`planilla_horarios_cab` `cab`
        ON
            (
                (
                    `cab`.`id_planilla_horarios_cab` = `det`.`id_planilla_horarios_cab`
                )
            )
        )
    WHERE
        (
            (
                STR_TO_DATE(
                    CONCAT(
                        `cab`.`ano_correspondiente`,
                        ',',
                        `cab`.`mes_correspondiente`,
                        ',',
                        `det`.`dia`
                    ),
                    '%Y,%m,%d'
                ) = `sc`.`fecha_solicitada`
            ) AND(
                `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante` = `det`.`id_agente`
            )
        )
) AS `cambio_por`
```

to test you could try replacing it with an empty string, as you have for the other two selects -

```
'' AS `cambio_por`
```

Each of the three outer selects has two subqueries in the select list to retrieve values from `sigsiste_bd.agentes` based on `sc.id_agente_solicitante`. These should probably be replaced by another join.

```
...
    (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`nombres`,
            ' ',
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`apellidos`
        )
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `agente_solicitante_nombre`,
(
    SELECT
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`imagen_perfil`
    FROM
        `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`
    WHERE
        (
            `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
        )
) AS `imagen_perfil_solicitante`,
...
FROM
    (
        `sigsiste_bd`.`solicitudes_cambio_horario` `sc`
    LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes` `a`
    ON
        (
            (
                `a`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado`
            )
        )
    )
```

would become

```
...
CONCAT(`agente_solicitante`.`nombres`, ' ', `agente_solicitante`.`apellidos`) AS `agente_solicitante_nombre`,
`agente_solicitante`.`imagen_perfil` AS `imagen_perfil_solicitante`,
...
FROM `sigsiste_bd`.`solicitudes_cambio_horario` `sc`
LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes` `a`
    ON `a`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitado`
LEFT JOIN `sigsiste_bd`.`agentes` `agente_solicitante`
    ON `agente_solicitante`.`id_agente` = `sc`.`id_agente_solicitante`
```

Your expression for `nombre_mes` can be simplified -

```
/* From */
CONCAT(
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_cobertura`, '%d') USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        MONTHNAME(`sc`.`fecha_cobertura`) USING utf8mb4
    ),
    ' de ',
    CONVERT(
        DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_cobertura`, '%Y') USING utf8mb4
    )
) AS `nombre_mes`,

/* To */
CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(`sc`.`fecha_solicitada`, '%d de %M de %Y') USING utf8mb4) AS `nombre_mes`,
```